# Peugeot 207 2009, issues with LPG

Tags: misfire, peugeot, cold-start, lpg, cold-weather

My 207, since about a year, is having some troubles 'passing' to LPG. It starts regularly on petrol then, as soon as the ECU switches to LPG, if I'm not pushing on the gas, it shuts down. My work-around is to 'manually' go on petrol mode and switch LPG on as soon as the thermometer starts moving. What can be wrong? 
I add that few weeks ago I got a 'misfire' error. But after few hundreds km the error light went off.

Spark-plugs changed about 20000 km ago

UPDATE:
I brought my car to the gas-specialist, he found a leaking lung, after replacement my car started to work properly again.
He told me the leakage was directed to the manifold enriching the carburetion too much causing engine problems on startup. This fix also improved my car's autonomy.

Comment: I really don't know much about how the system is supposed to work, but I'd start checking the different items which allows the system to work, such as the temp sensor itself. Does the vehicle use two of them (one for the gauge and one for the ECU)? Are there any checks you can do to the LPG manifold to ensure proper function? Is there actually LPG in the tank? How do you know when it switches over on normal operation? If there's an indicator light, is it functioning?

Comment: On normal operation it kicked in about 2 minutes after engine started, as sensors I don't know. Thank is full and manifold I think is good (the car go well at full gas and also I wouldn't have the 2-year inspection passed)